# How to divide 2 doubles from textfields in swift4

Tags: swift, double

I create a small app for calculating the perfect weight of users, I converted the strings from TextFields to Doubles to use them in my operation but I didn't get the correct result. I got it just in the case of dividing Int for Int, but I want the result as double.

```
@IBAction func CalculPerfectWeight(_ sender: Any)

{
    let UserWeightValue = userWeight.text
    let dbValue1 = NSString(string: UserWeightValue!).doubleValue

    let UserLengthVAlue = userLength.text
    let dbValue2 = NSString(string: UserLengthVAlue!).doubleValue

    let squareRoot: Double = sqrt(dbValue2)
    let PerfectWeight: Double? = Double(dbValue1 / squareRoot)

   PerfectWeightLbl.isHidden = false
   BackButtOut.isHidden = false

    PerfectWeightLbl.text = "Your Perfect Weight is : \(String(describing: PerfectWeight))"
}
```

Comment: Just stating that you *“didn't get the correct result”* is not helpful. What are the input values in the text fields? What values are computed and what result do you expect?

Comment: Did you try to debug or use any print statement to understand what happens? How are decimal numbers entered with your locale, do you use dot (.) or decimal (,) as the decimalseparator?

Comment: (Double(txtField1.text) ?? 0.00) / (Double(txtField2.text) ?? 0.00)

Comment: @Maddy Possible division by zero

Comment: @JoakimDanielson oh sorry. you are right. (Double(txtField1.text) ?? 0.00) / (Double(txtField2.text) ?? 1.00)

Comment: @Maddy text property is optional. You also forgot to force unwrap it

Comment: the values in textfields should be numbers

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 let result = firstValue.dividing(by: secondValue)
 print(result)
```

or if that above doesn't work it could be your double values are out of range then use this

```
             let firstValue = NSDecimalNumber(firstValue)
             let secondValue = NSDecimalNumber(secondValue)

             let result = firstValue.dividing(by: secondValue)
 print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't calculate a perfect weight for a person by only using their height and weight so my guess is that you are trying to calculate BMI and in that case your error is that you are using square root instead of square (power of 2). So the solution if my guess is right is that you should use `pow` instead of `sqrt`

Here is my modified version of your code using `pow` instead of `sort`

```
if let weight = Double(userWeight.text!), let length = Double(userLength.text!) {
    let result = weight / pow(length, 2.0)
    PerfectWeightLbl.text = "Your BMI is : \(String(describing: result))"
}
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your help, i modify my code like that one but i didn't get any result. the text label doesn't change.

Comment: Did you try to debug the code or add some print statements?

Comment: i debug the code. i change the label text string with mine and i make everything as well but no result.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "no result".

Comment: What happens if you use your original code but changes sqrt to pow as mentioned?

Comment: inside the simulator in label text (PefectWeightLbl) i get nothing, nothing changed.

Comment: But what do you see in the debugger? Do you get past the `if`, what is in the text field variables etc

Answer (score -1):

I make my code very simple to let you understand more about my issue. this is my new code :

```
@IBAction func CalculPerfectWeight(_ sender: Any)

{
    /* This is My Variables 
      @IBOutlet weak var userWeight: UITextField!
      @IBOutlet weak var userLength: UITextField!
      @IBOutlet weak var PerfectWeightLbl: UILabel!
    */

    PerfectWeightLbl.isHidden = false
    BackButtOut.isHidden = false

    let UserWeightInput: Double? = Double(userWeight.text!)
    let UserLengthInput: Double? = Double(userLength.text!)
    let ThePerfectWeight: Double = UserLengthInput! * UserLengthInput! / UserWeightInput!
    PerfectWeightLbl.text = "Your Perfect Wight's \(ThePerfectWeight)"
}
```

my result should be double, for example :

- the user normal weight is: 75
- the use Length is : 1.77

I want to calculate the perfect weight with this equation :

Perfect weight = (Length x Length) / Normal Weight, that's mean : Perfect Weight = (1.77 x 1.77) / 75 = 23.93

but xcode its give me another result

Comment: Don't post further info as an answer, update your question [by editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58464469/edit) instead and don't just say you get another result, include the incorrect result.